# Android sequential touching buttons

Tags: android

As I am new in Android programming, I need some help to implement the following scenario:

I have two buttons (1 & 2) one above the other and I need to implement the following three actions:

1. When we touch down each of the buttons, a soundpool plays a sound (for button1 plays sound 'a'  and for button2 plays sound 'b'). Each sound has duration of 10 seconds. While we hold the button (or move inside button), the sound plays the corresponding sound and when we stop press it, the sound should stop (so if we hold the button1 for 3 seconds, we want to hear the first 3 seconds of sound 'a').
2. If we hold the button1 for over 10 seconds, we want the sound 'a' to be repeated (until we stop pressing the button).
3. If we move out of the button1 and still pressing the screen, we want:
   a) in case we touch button2, to stop play sound 'a' and start directly play sound 'b' (as long as we hold button2),
   b) in case we touch out of the two buttons, to stop play sound 'a'.

The following code implements 1 (besides the case of moving inside button)  and 3b).

```
boolean pressedUp = false;

SoundPool p1;
SoundPool p2;

int s1;
int s2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    if (pressedUp == false) {
                        pressedUp = true;
                        p1.play(s1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                {
                    p1.autoPause();
                    pressedUp = false;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                {
                    p1.autoPause();
                    pressedUp = false;
                }

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    if (pressedUp == false) {
                        pressedUp = true;
                        p2.play(s2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                {
                    p2.autoPause();
                    pressedUp = false;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                {
                    p2.autoPause();
                    pressedUp = false;
                }

            }

            return true;
        }
    });


    p1 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    s1 = p1.load(this, R.raw.a, 1);

    p2 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    s2 = p2.load(this, R.raw.b, 1);
 }
```

I would appreciate any help to implement the whole scenario.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest that you only include a single question in a post. In each post, you should describe what you tried and what went wrong, without including any more code or conext than needed. For example, you might ask how to detect if a button has been touched for more than ten seconds. It's not clear that its controlling a SoundPool is relevant.

Comment: Hello @espertus. Thank you for your comment. As it is my first question, I'll take your advice into account for the next time. Do you have any suggestion to complete my code?

Comment: No, I do not. Sorry.